# How do I return a hash map from HttpResponse?

Tags: java, jackson, java-11

I am new to Java. I am trying to hit an external API and am a little lost of how I translate the response back to a hashmap. All the examples I see online for interacting with APIs assume you want it back as a string or have an existing POJO you want to map things back to. I literally just care about extracting values in the response. In the below example, I am trying to extract out the access token from an API (and, later, in methods I haven't defined yet, use said access token to retrieve information from different endpoints).

I'm not wedded to Java 11's built-in library, either, if there is a library that requires less boilerplate.

I'm a little surprised none of my Googling has surfaced examples of API consumption where a hashmap is returned... Is converting into a self-defined POJO standard for Java? Feels like a lot of unnecessary boilerplate when I don't care about a lot of the JSON's fields.

(Also, if there is anything else wrong with this snippet, I'm open to suggestions!)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class AlationApiClient {

    private static final HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    private static final String alationUrl = "someUrl";
    private String refreshToken;
    private Integer userId;
    private String accessToken;

    public AlationApiClient(String refreshToken, Integer userId) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    private static String createRequestBody(Map<String, Object> data) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return objectMapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(data);
    }

    public Object getAccessToken(String refreshToken, Integer userId) throws JsonProcessingException {

        String url = alationUrl + "/integration/v1/createAPIAccessToken/";
        Map<String, Object> data = Map.of(
                "refresh_token", this.refreshToken,
                "user_id", this.userId
        );

        String requestBody = createRequestBody(data);

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
                .build();

        return AlationApiClient.client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenApply(???) // what do I do here to put things into a hashmap??
                .join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse JSON to (Hash)Map? `ObjectMapper#readValue`

Comment: you don't need to necessarily create pojo objects. you can also just work with JSONObjects directly. Also, you can just create pojo objects for just the fields you need/want. Don't need to specify the entire response. It will just fill the fields you listed in your pojo and ignore the rest

Comment: @knittl how do I do that in the context of .thenApply?  Or should I do it outside of .thenApply?

Comment: @oddnumberedcat `thenApply` (likely to be defined in `CompletableStage`/`CompletableFuture`) expects a `Function<T, R>`, in your case that would be a `Function<String, Map<String, Object>>` (or `Function<byte[], Map<String, Object>>`). This can be expressed as a lambda, e.g. `.thenApply(body -> objectMapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>{}))`.

Comment: The use of `sendAsync` and CompletableFuture needlessly complicates this.  Just use `String body = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();`.